# Deploying two isolated application instances with nginx ingress and tls termination in the same AKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

Objective: run 2 separate application instances with nginx ingress controller and tls termination in the same AKS cluster.

I have already been successfully doing this with 1 application instance. However, when I try to deploy 2, it doesn't work.

Hereafter the operations I do, starting from a brand new AKS cluster (the installation of the 2 instances of the application in the two namespaces tenant11 and tenant12 are not shown here)

```
kubectl create namespace tenant11
kubectl create namespace tenant12
helm --namespace tenant11 install ing11 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.ingressClass=class11 --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=class11 --set controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue="k8s.io/class11-controller" --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"=tenant11
helm --namespace tenant12 install ing12 ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.ingressClass=class12 --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=class12 --set controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue="k8s.io/class12-controller" --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"=tenant12
kubectl apply -f .\ingress-class11.yaml
kubectl apply -f .\ingress-class12.yaml
helm install certman11 jetstack/cert-manager --namespace tenant11 --set installCRDs=true
helm install certman12 jetstack/cert-manager --namespace tenant12
kubectl apply -f .\cluster-issuer11.yaml
kubectl apply -f .\cluster-issuer12.yaml
kubectl apply -f .\ingress11.yaml
kubectl apply -f .\ingress12.yaml
```

Now the yaml files (only those with 11, the 12 ones are the same with 12 in place of 11)

```
# ingress-class11.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: class11
  namespace: tenant11
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/class11-controller
```

```
# cluster-issuer11.yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt11
  namespace: tenant11
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: <my email>
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: class11
```

```
# ingress11.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tenant11-rms-ingress
  namespace: tenant11
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt11
spec:
  ingressClassName: class11
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - tenant11.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com
      secretName: tls-secret11
  rules:
  - host: tenant11.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tenant11-rms-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

When all is deployed, the browser turns back an invalid certificate issue, as if the certificate used is the fake one (self signed):
[image]

Again, if I apply the same exact process for only one instance, using the standard nginx ingress class, all works fine.

Could someone help me in finding what I am doing wrong. I suspect I am not configuring correctly the certificate pipeline, but couldn't find a working example.

EDIT

I report here nginx ingress controller logs records as per comments requests

```
10.244.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2021:06:17:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36" 472 0.000 [tenant11-tenant11-rms-service-80] [] - - - - 1b66f9b58d75a558f7085145716777ce
10.244.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2021:06:17:08 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 503 592 "https://tenant11.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36" 134 0.000 [tenant11-tenant11-rms-service-80] [] - - - - 8d6d8fad03a1d75827e2d20789e06690
10.244.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2021:06:17:08 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/qaVxof8GVBvcbYhxouGh-F_c1wf7CcBDSE1IbqN33d8 HTTP/1.1" 308 164 "-" "cert-manager/v1.5.3 (clean)" 220 0.000 [tenant11-tenant11-rms-service-80] [] - - - - 03e16721c7893a1b3a6eadc94679f205
10.244.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2021:06:17:08 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/qaVxof8GVBvcbYhxouGh-F_c1wf7CcBDSE1IbqN33d8 HTTP/1.1" 503 190 "http://tenant11.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/qaVxof8GVBvcbYhxouGh-F_c1wf7CcBDSE1IbqN33d8" "cert-manager/v1.5.3 (clean)" 350 0.000 [tenant11-tenant11-rms-service-80] [] - - - - 2e54b66e11c771f7904e4472797cc357
10.244.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2021:06:17:18 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/qaVxof8GVBvcbYhxouGh-F_c1wf7CcBDSE1IbqN33d8 HTTP/1.1" 308 164 "-" "cert-manager/v1.5.3 (clean)" 220 0.000 [tenant11-tenant11-rms-service-80] [] - - - - 5aedc0bb146bcfc8dd114ae453fc1633
```

Comment: Hi Franco, could you go to your ing11 namespace and observe the CRD, cert, order and chanllenge?
I want to make sure you have no issue with the cert manager cert issuing.

Comment: @RyanSiu there are issues. For example the challenge status/reason is 'Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code ''404'', expected '200''. But how do  fix them?

Comment: Hi Franco, could you try the annotation `acme.cert-manager.io/http01-ingress-class`? Please check this doc, https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/ingress/, for more info.

Comment: @RyanSiu with your recommended change now the error is '1 sync.go:185] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="propagation check failed" "error"="wrong status code '503', expected '200'" "dnsName"="tenant11.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com" "resource_kind"="Challenge" "resource_name"="tls-secret11-jv7br-2454640939-4224274127" "resource_namespace"="tenant11" "resource_version"="v1" "type"="HTTP-01" '

Comment: I have tried to access your site. It returns as 503. Could you check the NGINX logs to see if the ingress can reach the service?

Comment: @RyanSiu please see the records in the main post

Comment: So, let's restart from the beginning. You delete all the ingress, cert, order and challenge object. Redeploy it to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @RyanSiu As I am working with AKS, to delete all  I simply delete the cluster and create one new. I have done this multiple times and repeated the procedure. It always ends up the same way